# SQL UDF order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

im new to microsoft sql however i have some experience with oracle, what i'm trying to do is to return a view function with a UDF and have a result column that is ordered

```
CREATE FUNCTION FunctionSort (  @Name varchar(60), @familyName varchar(60) )

RETURNS table
AS
return 
(
    select Name, familyName, familyName + ',' + Name as Result  
    from Employees 
    where Name = @Name and familyName = @familyName
    order by Result  asc
)
GO
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve by this function ?? you are passing two variables and then simply doing some concatenation on them strings ?? and also you cannot use order by clause in a function definition.

Comment: I would like to get 2 parameters from a select function, and then return the column with an extra column that display the name and familyname ordered.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is take out the ORDER BY clause from you function definition and use it when you actually call the function ....
**Function Definition**

```
CREATE FUNCTION FunctionSort (  @Name varchar(60), @familyName varchar(60) )
RETURNS table
AS
return 
(
    select Name, familyName, familyName + ',' + Name as Result  
    from Employees 
    where Name = @Name and familyName = @familyName
)
GO
```

**Call Function**

```
SELECT * FROM FunctionSort (@Name, @familyName)
ORDER BY Result ASC
```